# Running python unit tests as part of bamboo build

Tags: bamboo, python-unittest

I need to run python units test cases as part of bamboo build step and the build needs to fail if unit tests fail.

For this, I have a Script step in bamboo build and i am trying to run the following in it:

```
python -m unittest discover /test
```

Here, /test folder has all the unit tests. 
The output of the above script it

```
Ran (0) tests
```

So the problem is that bamboo isn't able to discover these tests. Bamboo agent is linux.

Wondering if anyone has done such a thing before and has any suggestions.

Comment: Is `/test` supposed to be an absolute path or relative?

Comment: Absolute path. Even when I go inside the build machine and run tests there, it just doesn't discover any tests. Works fine in windows. Not sure if it's a bamboo problem or something to do with linux

Comment: Are the tests actually mounted at `/test` on the build bot? Does the build user have permission to view `/test`?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked. Used -p (pattern) attribute to discover/run the unit tests in bamboo (unix build agent)

python -m unittest discover -s test -p "T*.py"

Note: 1. all my test cases start with "T" e.g. Test_check.py
      2. "test" is the package where all my test cases are.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured it out, likely because in windows filenames aren't case sensitive but in Linux they are...

And you're test file named Test_xxxx.py isn't the same as test_xxxx.py which is the pattern that discovery is trying to use...